# iOS and Google Cloud Messaging: Missing push notifications in series of notifications

Tags: ios, curl, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using Google Cloud Messaging to receive push notifications in an iOS app. To see how reliable the system is, I performed two tests.
1. receive notifications while the app is in foreground
   called curl 1 in the following
2. receive notifications while the app is in background. The iOS homescreen is visible. Then the device is locked.
   called curl 2, 3, 4 in the following

For both tests I use a terminal program to send 10 push notifications to GCM in a row.

```
#!/bin/bash
api_key="MYAPYKEYXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
reg_id="MYREGIDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

for i in `seq 1 10`;
        do
            echo "Sending message $i"
            curl    --header "Authorization: key=$api_key"  --header Content-Type:"application/json"    https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"$reg_id\"], \"data\":{\"message\": \"This is $i\"}, \"content_available\":true}"
            echo " "
        done
```

My AppDelegate.swift contains the following code: For this test I'm just logging the received notifications to the console.

```
func application( application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
            self.log.debug("\(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]): type: \(userInfo) ")

        // This works only if the app started the GCM service
        GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
        // Handle the received message
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
            userInfo: userInfo)
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
func application( application: UIApplication,
    didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
    fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        self.log.debug("\(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]): type: \(userInfo) ")

        // This works only if the app started the GCM service
        GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
        // Handle the received message
        // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
            userInfo: userInfo)
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
}

    // [END ack_message_reception]
```

#### curl 1 : running while app is active

```
$ sh gcm-push-curl.sh 
Sending message 1
{"multicast_id":7601092806058312069,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966587095558%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 2
{"multicast_id":5909902520187109640,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966587866963%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 3
{"multicast_id":4614499459908171704,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966589361277%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 4
{"multicast_id":8134668915396219272,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966590641578%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 5
{"multicast_id":4784965394490169762,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966591587472%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 6
{"multicast_id":6241530976591223030,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966594764987%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 7
{"multicast_id":8978902798439854756,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966595671922%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 8
{"multicast_id":6283825418645144982,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966596474541%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 9
{"multicast_id":8120719633509436218,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966597242071%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 10
{"multicast_id":8512105467086003642,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966597991847%d9588296d9588296"}]}
```

#### curl 2: running while app is in background and device is locked

```
$sh gcm-push-curl.sh 
Sending message 1
{"multicast_id":5588705638430973508,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966661606755%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 2
{"multicast_id":9016701196490961038,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966662368880%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 3
{"multicast_id":8811760824655650118,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966664079778%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 4
{"multicast_id":5409935873727765078,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966665050940%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 5
{"multicast_id":7729732231428218287,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966666508932%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 6
{"multicast_id":8188050074826382607,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966667585382%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 7
{"multicast_id":5913793804137018252,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966671009307%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 8
{"multicast_id":5601975420774004308,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966672984512%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 9
{"multicast_id":8457313732470913239,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966673716583%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 10
{"multicast_id":5371949804462995150,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966675441327%d9588296d9588296"}]}
```

#### curl 3: running while app is in background and device is locked once again

```
$ sh gcm-push-curl.sh 
Sending message 1
{"multicast_id":5557012639197983768,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966719944546%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 2
{"multicast_id":4730409051405748208,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966724620582%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 3
{"multicast_id":5530580902639958686,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966725438291%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 4
{"multicast_id":9111474059722223027,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966727055882%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 5
{"multicast_id":7841377277124478181,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966728970341%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 6
{"multicast_id":5594543271725809615,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966730800067%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 7
{"multicast_id":8685309308966690464,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966731640101%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 8
{"multicast_id":8859997925201491765,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966735618351%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 9
{"multicast_id":8830947759563422702,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966737433853%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 10
{"multicast_id":5660703487823801785,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446966738664391%d9588296d9588296"}]}
```

#### curl 4: running while app is in background, device still locked once more

```
$sh gcm-push-curl.sh 
Sending message 1
{"multicast_id":4866730914828951532,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446967658074261%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 2
{"multicast_id":8385741491167809594,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446967658837166%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 3
{"multicast_id":7340882174172500805,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446967660847155%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 4
{"multicast_id":8822097918345564456,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446967661759583%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 5
{"multicast_id":9155633918940805212,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446967662891127%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 6
{"multicast_id":8374566084159111686,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446967663658639%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 7
{"multicast_id":5062396269674637650,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446967664476061%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 8
{"multicast_id":5632447549491506026,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446967665191507%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 9
{"multicast_id":5582459520681321352,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446967665936985%d9588296d9588296"}]} 
Sending message 10
{"multicast_id":7328958609399996860,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1446967668825005%d9588296d9588296"}]}
```

The results:

#### After Curl 1

```
2015-11-08 08:09:47.718 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966587095558%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 1, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966587095558%d9588296d9588296] 
2015-11-08 08:09:48.434 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966587866963%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 2, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966587866963%d9588296d9588296] 
2015-11-08 08:09:49.973 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966589361277%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 3, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966589361277%d9588296d9588296] 
2015-11-08 08:09:51.401 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966590641578%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 4, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966590641578%d9588296d9588296] 
2015-11-08 08:09:52.222 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966591587472%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 5, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966591587472%d9588296d9588296] 
2015-11-08 08:09:55.397 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966594764987%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 6, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966594764987%d9588296d9588296] 
2015-11-08 08:09:56.317 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966595671922%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 7, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966595671922%d9588296d9588296] 
2015-11-08 08:09:57.036 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966596474541%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 8, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966596474541%d9588296d9588296] 
2015-11-08 08:09:57.855 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966597242071%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 9, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966597242071%d9588296d9588296] 
2015-11-08 08:09:58.569 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966597991847%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 10, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966597991847%d9588296d9588296]
```

#### After Curl 2

```
2015-11-08 08:11:05.404 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966661606755%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 1, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966661606755%d9588296d9588296] 
2015-11-08 08:11:07.286 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966662368880%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 2, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966662368880%d9588296d9588296] 
2015-11-08 08:11:10.109 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966664079778%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 3, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966664079778%d9588296d9588296]
```

#### After Curl 3

```
2015-11-08 08:12:16.960 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966730800067%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 6, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966730800067%d9588296d9588296] 
2015-11-08 08:12:18.698 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966731640101%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 7, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966731640101%d9588296d9588296] 
2015-11-08 08:12:22.159 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966735618351%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 8, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966735618351%d9588296d9588296] 
    ### 30 seconds later...
2015-11-08 08:20:57.287 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446966738664391%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 10, gcm.message_id: 0:1446966738664391%d9588296d9588296]
```

#### After Curl 4

```
2015-11-08 08:27:41.779 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446967658074261%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 1, gcm.message_id: 0:1446967658074261%d9588296d9588296] 
2015-11-08 08:27:43.798 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446967658837166%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 2, gcm.message_id: 0:1446967658837166%d9588296d9588296] 
2015-11-08 08:27:49.739 [Debug] [main] [AppDelegate.swift:206] application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) > Optional(0:1446967662891127%d9588296d9588296): type: [aps: {
    "content-available" = 1;
}, message: This is 5, gcm.message_id: 0:1446967662891127%d9588296d9588296]
```

As you can see not all notifications are received when the device is locked. But some, some come delayed (No. 10 in curl 3).

I have no Idea what I can do about this, since notifications are received in general.

I hope somebody of you has any ideas.

Best Simon

Edit1: I reviewed the logs once and saw that `func application( application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])` is never called.

Answer (score 1):

GCM uses APNs to deliver messages when the application is not in the foreground. Notification delivery is [not guaranteed by APNs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

> Important: Delivery of notifications is a “best effort”, not
>   guaranteed. It is not intended to deliver data to your app, only to
>   notify the user that there is new data available.

I think sending content-available back to back messages through APNs while the app is not is the foreground like you are doing in your test, would result in dropped messages. Maybe a test with a longer delay would result is less dropped messages.

If your messages are high priority then consider [setting the priority value](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options?hl=en#setting-the-priority-of-a-message) of the message to high, but only if the message requires user interaction like a chat message.